# Can you use AC to USB DC Converter To Power Pico W?

Tags: wifi, power

Can you use these types of converters/adapters to power the Pico W?
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002442614617.html

More importantly, when you'd look at the specs, what individual evaluation steps would you take and/or other important considerations in order to make the determination?

We have a bunch lying around that came with our phones over the years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a 5V usb power adapter to power a Pico W.

USB is 5V, no other steps or considerations to take into account.

Comment: Well this is good news then.  Would you have an idea as to why the info out there mostly points to using a "raspberry power supply" at 15-20 $ when a much cheaper one like in the link I posted in my question would work just fine?  Am I forgoing any function or capability by going with this solution VS outright power supplies?

Comment: I suspect info you are reading refers to Raspberry Pi power supplies not Raspberry Pico W power supplies. However the official power supplies are excellent and I always use them on my Raspberry Pi's and various devices. I would never buy a power supply from aliexpress.

Comment: That's to show the type of device not the source.  Regarding steps or considerations, doesn't matter if a 5v AC to USB converter has X amps and/or X watts, it'll work with the Pico W?  If not, why?

Comment: USB 2.0 power is supposed to be 500 mA, although with power supplies/chargers it is commonly more.  I doubt there are many around that put out *less*, and that is enough to power a Pico.   I don't know what the wifi chip requires although they commonly **consume up to an amp @5V (so don't get anything less than that).**

Comment: @goldilocks I've just swapped the Pico W for a regular Pico and the setup is behaving the same.  My takeaway so far is:  So long as "any" USB source ends up bringing 5V and at least 1amp to a barebones Pico setup it should be fine.  Regarding the WiFi chip, would the mere fact that it's on the Pico W cause it to consume more power than a regular Pico would, even if my micropython code doesn't use it?  I have a voltmeter, where would I put the prongs to get a Voltage/Wattage/Amperage reading?

Comment: Not sure why I call it a voltmeter, it's a multimeter.  I'll find where to put the prongs.

Comment: No, the wifi chip will only use a significant amount of power when in use (it's the radio part that guzzles energy).